# how can i access the raw xml of the saml token?

Tags: c#, saml, wif, ws-federation

I can get all the claims values with code like this:

```
ClaimsPrincipal cp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;            
ClaimsIdentity cid = (ClaimsIdentity)cp.Identity;

foreach (Claim claim in cid.Claims)
{
   ...
}
```

but i want to be able to read the entire token as i suspect a some info i need is in a non-attribute section of the token.
I've read about the security token visualizer control, but it's not something i can use because i don't want end users seeing the control output, but would like to send the raw token xml via email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you must configure WIF to save the "BootstrapContext":

```
<system.identityModel>
  <identityConfiguration saveBootstrapContext="true">
```

Then you can use the Property "BootstrapContext" on the "ClaimsIdentity"

```
ClaimsPrincipal cp = Thread.CurrentPrincipal as ClaimsPrincipal;
ClaimsIdentity cid = (ClaimsIdentity)cp.Identity; 
BootstrapContext bc = cid.BootstrapContext as BootstrapContext;
```

And use the "Token" Property on the BootstrapContext to get the raw xml of the saml token.

See also:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.claims.claimsidentity.bootstrapcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.tokens.bootstrapcontext(v=vs.110).aspx

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2012/11/30/using-the-bootstrapcontext-property-in-net-4-5-2/

Comment: i've accepted the answer.  i get a BootstrapContext reference but the .Token property is null.  the .SecurityToken property looks good, but i need the raw text of the .Token property.   any suggestions?

Comment: solved!

SecurityToken bootstrapToken = bc.SecurityToken;         

using (var wrtr = XmlWriter.Create(sbToken)) 
{
   new Saml2SecurityTokenHandler(new SamlSecurityTokenRequirement()).WriteToken(wrtr, bootstrapToken);
 }
theXml = sbToken.ToString();